# ¿Cómo elegir el tamaño de memoria para exportar en WebGL Usando Unity3D?

Tags: unity3d, webgl

He tratado de configurar la exportación de un proyecto simple a [webgl](/questions/tagged/webgl) en [unity3d](/questions/tagged/unity3d) pero no le atino a la cantidad de memoria que debo de asignarle en el `PlayerSettings`.

Si le pongo 16 obtengo

[image: prueba con 16 megas]

Si le pongo 60 obtengo

[image: prueba con 60 megas]

Experimentalmente hallé que en lo localhost funciona perfectamente con 40

[image: con 40 megas]

Pero entiendo que depende en gran parte del equipo que lo corra ( El mío tiene 16 gigas de *RAM* y un procesador gráfico *nVidia* de 1 Giga )

¿Existe alguna manera o alguna fórmula para calcular la cantidad apropiada para que funcione en la mayor cantidad de computadoras?
¿Debo cambiar mi configuración al exportarlo a un servidor de *hosting*?
¿Existe una forma en que se asigne esa memoria dinámicamente y funcione en todas las computadoras?

Comment: Por curiosidad, ves tú el mismo comportamiento cuando corre en Chrome o Internet Explorer?

Comment: de hecho al googlearlo encontré que era un error de Chrome principalmente debido a su capacidad de devorar ram indiscrimiandamente. En todos los navegadores es igual, tienen sus parámetros de memoria que idealmente debes de estimar de antemano para no tener pérdidas en rendimiento al realizar el renderizado.

Comment: @Chofoteddy Podrías haberme avisado por correo antes... no estoy seguro de poder resolverlo en 6 días por falta de tiempo... ( cualquier ayuda en `primefaces` me lo hará más disponible :P )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explicación

He encontrado una solución que al parecer me funciona bastante bien, aunque hace que la carga del juego sea más lenta de lo normal.

Se trata de hacer la generación del juego mediante un `script de Editor`.
Al ponerle `@MenuItem("Build/BuildWebplayer")` hago que el script aparezca en un menú de Unity y que se ejecute al darle click.
Le agrego el parámetro `ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH` y lo establezco a verdadero para que el sistema decida automáticamente cuanta memoria necesita, empezando desde la mínima requerida.
Le agrego los niveles que deseo en un arreglo de cadenas y le especifico el nombre de la carpeta, en mi caso será `WebPlayerBuild`.

---

### Código

```
@MenuItem("Build/BuildWebplayer")
static function MyBuild(){
    PlayerSettings.SetPropertyString("emscriptenArgs", "-s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1", BuildTargetGroup.WebGL);
        var levels : String[] = ["Assets/planta baja.unity", "Assets/poner cosas.unity"];
        BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer( levels, "WebPlayerBuild", 
                       BuildTarget.WebGL, BuildOptions.None); 
}
```

Comment: Mil gracias señor @Choffotedy :D